# Chametz left over Pesach -- Must be burnt?

Tags: halacha, food, passover, chametz-leaven, disposal

Chametz that belonged to a Jew over Pesach is prohibted (ossur) to have benefit (haneh) from (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Siman 448 Sif 3.)

Is it enough that this chametz simply be thrown away or must one burn it (or any other "acceptable" way of completely destroying or getting rid of the chametz? Just like chametz from before Pesach or that which was found on Pesach) Does anyone discuss this?

Comment: Why would this have to be burnt? Chametz on Pesach itself doesn't have to be burnt.

Comment: @DoubleAA Source?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=16&perek=3&halocha=11&hilite= but I think you are confusing who needs to bring a source to justify their point: the one assuming the restriction or the one not assuming the restriction?

Comment: @DoubleAA As always if I have a source I wouldn't be asking! A very big Rov asked this question...

Comment: I don't really care who asked it. You want to tell me you have no reason at all to think burning might be applicable and you are just asking about burning randomly?? If you have reason to suspect burning then please include that in the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA I realized what basic point was bothering you and edited the question to reflect this....My point is hopefully better understood now in the question (i.e. is it like chametz from before pesach or found on pesach or is it different.) But in any case I see nothing wrong with asking random questions.

Comment: 1) If that is your point, just **say it** in the question. 2) Asking questions without motivation is discouraged here. A questions which says "Is it enough that this chametz simply be thrown away or must one drench it in sulfuric acid?" is poor as is this one until you can explain why you might think there is any reason your latter option is a possible requirement. So -1

Comment: @DoubleAA - My motivation is to find out if the chametz after pesach has the same din like from before....Just my point, huh? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28257/1884

Comment: What are you proving from your answer? What do you mean "Just [your] point"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that from the Shulchan Aruch HaRav in Siman 435 Sif-Katan 4 that chametz that was left over Pesach also needs "biur" just like the Chametz from before Pesach and wouldn't be enough to simply throw it away.

Comment: @DoubleAA + !?!?!?

Comment: I don't follow. Isn't throwing it away a valid form of "biur" before Pesach?